# Custom output to subresource operations

Tags: api-platform.com

Is it possible to use custom output on subresource operations?

Lets say I have an entity User and a related subresource entity Post.

When requesting Post collectionOperations get and itemOperations get I am using a custom output class and a transformer to fill data from Post into the output - standard api-platform thing.

Now I want to do the same with the subresource so when requesting GET /users/{id}/posts I would like to receive posts in the same output form I am getting in the direct requests to Post endpoints.

I tried defining it in the configuration section subresourceOperations but it doesn't seem to work

```
resources:
App\Entity\User:
    subresourceOperations:
        api_users_posts_get_subresource:
            output: App\Model\PostOutput
    properties:
        posts:
            subresource:
                maxDepth: 1
                resourceClass: App\Entity\Post
```

Comment: `output` param related to target entity (i.e. `Post`) and will use for every request to corresponding path (`/posts`) both directly and via subresources.

So I think you should remove `api_users_posts_get_subresource` section.

Comment: @shvv can you write an answer with yaml example, that way I will be able to accept it if correct